# on the convergence of a certain integral

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

If I have an entire function $\phi$ such that it is of exponential order zero. I.e for all $\rho > 0$ we get $|\phi(s)|\le C_\rho e^{|s|^{\rho}}$. Furthermore, I have an extreme decay in the Taylor coefficients of $\phi$

Does the following integral converge for $\Re(z)>0$?

$$\int_1^\infty \phi(w)w^{-z-1}\,\mathrm dw.$$

Essentially, I'm wondering if we can bound $\phi$. I'm thinking this is possible if its Taylor coefficients decay sufficiently fast enough. Is there a direct stronger bound on $\phi$ I can find by knowing bounds on its Taylor coefficients?

I'm at a loss observing the growth and convergence of this integral. Any help, literature, hints, comments, insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks much too strong as stated.  The hypothesis holds for
$\phi(s) = s^n$ but the integral doesn't converge until $z>n$.
If $\phi(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n s^n$ with each $a_n>0$
then the integral doesn't converge for any $z$, and if the $a_n$
decay quickly enough then you'll have exponential order zero.
For example, $\phi(s) = \prod_{r=0}^\infty (1 + 2^{-r} s)$ should work.

Comment: So you conclude that it doesn't converge if the $a_n$ are all positive, no matter how fast its taylor coefficients decay to zero?
That makes sense. I'm confused because you said $\phi$ would work, does that mean it's entire of order zero and converges, or what?

Comment: Right.  I meant "should work" as a counterexample, being entire of order zero but still growing too fast for the integral to converge.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was working in fishy territory. I guess I'll have to work around this result. :)